# How to pass async data as input property angular?

Tags: angular

There is a root component with children components inside:

```
<app-document-card-sidebar [sections]="sections" [document]="documentObs | async"></app-document-card-sidebar>
<app-document-card [sections]="sections" [document]="documentObs | async"></app-document-card>
```

Root component is:

```
   public sections: any[] = [];
   public documentObs: Observable<any>;

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.documentObs = this.route.paramMap.pipe(
            filter((params) => params.has('id')),
            switchMap((params) => this.documentCardService.get(+params.get('id'))),
            tap(() => {
                this.sections = (this.documentSidebarCreator.factoryMethod() as DocumentSidebar).getSidebarMenuItemsBasedResponse();
            }),
        );
    }
```

As you can see I try to pass async data getting from route by id to children components as:

```
[document]="documentObs | async"
```

Is it correct way to do that? It does not work for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should actually work. However you could wrap the `async` pipe in a `ng-container` to trigger the cold observable only once instead of multiple `async` pipes.

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="(documentObs | async) as document">
  <app-document-card-sidebar [sections]="sections" [document]="document"></app-document-card-sidebar>
  <app-document-card [sections]="sections" [document]="document"></app-document-card>
</ng-container>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1**

*Root*

```
<app-document-card [sections]="sections" [document]="documentObs"></app-document-card>
```

*Child*

```
@Input document: Observable<DocumentType>;
_document: DocumentType;

ngOnInit() {
  this.document.subscribe(res => this._document = res);
}
```

**Option 2**

*Root*

```
   public sections: any[] = [];
   public documentObs: Observable<DocumentType>;
   public document: DocumentType;

   ngOnInit(): void {
        this.documentObs = this.route.paramMap.pipe(
            filter((params) => params.has('id')),
            switchMap((params) => this.documentCardService.get(+params.get('id'))),
            tap(() => {
                this.sections = (this.documentSidebarCreator.factoryMethod() as DocumentSidebar).getSidebarMenuItemsBasedResponse();
            }),
        );
        this.documentObs.subscribe(res => this.document = res);
    }
```

*HTML*

```
<app-document-card [sections]="sections" [document]="document"></app-document-card>
```

**Option 3 by Michael D.**

```
<ng-container *ngIf="(documentObs | async) as document">
  <app-document-card-sidebar [sections]="sections" [document]="document"></app-document-card-sidebar>
  <app-document-card [sections]="sections" [document]="document"></app-document-card>
</ng-container>
```

***PS: Always remember to unsubscribe onDestroy.***